# How can I change source folders en masse in Wise Installation Studio?

Tags: installation, wise

I've got an existing Wise .wsi script that I would like to convert to using relative paths, but the problem is that it includes about 330 files and the only way I've found to fix the paths are to go into each file's Details and adjust the path manually (from Installation Expert: Files screen, right click and select Details). Am I going to have to do this manual process 330 times or is there a way to change the .wsi script without using this crappy GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to go to the Tools menu and select "Convert Source Paths". A dialog pops up that will allow you to convert paths to relative and specify that newly added files always use relative paths. The "Change All Paths to Relative" didn't work for me, but changing just folder paths at least took less time than editing every file's details.